# react js material ui treeView change text color of tree item's label

Tags: reactjs, treeview, material-ui

I have material ui tree with nested tree items. I want to change the color of tree item's label only. When I applied  `style={{ backgroundColor: 'green, color: 'red' }}` It changes the color of whole tree item including the expand icon etc that I don't want. I also tried

```
const applyTitle = (data) => {
    console.log("data", data)
    return (
      // 'testing title'
      <span style={{ color: 'purple' }} >{data.Title}</span>
    )
  }
```

and called it in `label={applyTitle(value.Title, value.ForeColor, value.BackColor)}` at tree item but it is not working when I use span but it works when I return normal text only.

How can I change label's color only?

Full Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
import { fade, makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring/web.cjs'; // web.cjs is required for IE 11 support

import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { green } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Filters from './../filters/filters';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';

const axios = require('axios');

function MinusSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon fontSize="inherit" {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0zM17.873 11.023h-11.826q-.375 0-.669.281t-.294.682v0q0 .401.294 .682t.669.281h11.826q.375 0 .669-.281t.294-.682v0q0-.401-.294-.682t-.669-.281z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function PlusSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon fontSize="inherit" {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0zM17.873 12.977h-4.923v4.896q0 .401-.281.682t-.682.281v0q-.375 0-.669-.281t-.294-.682v-4.896h-4.923q-.401 0-.682-.294t-.281-.669v0q0-.401.281-.682t.682-.281h4.923v-4.896q0-.401.294-.682t.669-.281v0q.401 0 .682.281t.281.682v4.896h4.923q.401 0 .682.281t.281.682v0q0 .375-.281.669t-.682.294z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function CloseSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon className="close" fontSize="inherit" {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M17.485 17.512q-.281.281-.682.281t-.696-.268l-4.12-4.147-4.12 4.147q-.294.268-.696.268t-.682-.281-.281-.682.294-.669l4.12-4.147-4.12-4.147q-.294-.268-.294-.669t.281-.682.682-.281.696 .268l4.12 4.147 4.12-4.147q.294-.268.696-.268t.682.281 .281.669-.294.682l-4.12 4.147 4.12 4.147q.294.268 .294.669t-.281.682zM22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function TransitionComponent(props) {
  const style = useSpring({
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(20px,0,0)' },
    to: { opacity: props.in ? 1 : 0, transform: `translate3d(${props.in ? 0 : 20}px,0,0)` },
  });

  return (
    <animated.div style={style}>
      <Collapse {...props} />
    </animated.div>
  );
}



TransitionComponent.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Show the component; triggers the enter or exit states
   */
  in: PropTypes.bool,
};

const StyledTreeItem = withStyles(theme => ({
  iconContainer: {
    '& .close': {
      opacity: 0.3,
    },
  },
  group: {
    // marginLeft: 1,
    // paddingLeft: 12,
    borderLeft: `1px dashed ${fade(theme.palette.text.primary, 0.4)}`,
  },
}))(props => <TreeItem {...props} TransitionComponent={TransitionComponent} />);

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 400,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 'initial',
    textAlign: "left",
    width: "1400px",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"

  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 1100,
  },
  backcolor: {
    backgroundColor: green
  }
});

export default function CustomizTreeView(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [showTable, createTable] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isSending, setIsSending] = useState(false)
  const isMounted = useRef(true)
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);

  // set isMounted to false when we unmount the component
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])

  const sendRequest = useCallback(async (params) => {
    console.log("params", params);
    // don't send again while we are sending
    if (isSending) return
    // update state
    setIsSending(true)
    // send the actual request
    await
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/healthdata.json')
        .then(res => {
          console.log("res", res)
          setData(res.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    // once the request is sent, update state again
    if (isMounted.current) // only update if we are still mounted
      setIsSending(false)
  }, [isSending]) // update the callback if the state changes

  const handleClick = (id, node, title) => {
    setIsSending(true)
    let tableData;
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/${node}/id${id}.json`)
      .then(res => {
        return res.data
      }).then(data => {
        tableData = data;
        if (tableData) {
          createTable(
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
              <h3>{title}</h3>
              <Table className={classes.table} size="large" aria-label="a dense table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    {
                      Object.entries(tableData[0]).map(([key, value]) => {
                        return <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{key}</TableCell>
                      })
                    }
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {tableData.map((row, i) => (
                    <TableRow key={i}>
                      {
                        Object.keys(row).map(keyName => {
                          return <TableCell scope="row">{row[keyName]}</TableCell>
                        })
                      }
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          )
        } else {
          return createTable(<h3 style={{ color: 'red' }} >No Table Data Found For this record</h3>);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return createTable(<h3 style={{ color: 'red' }} >Not Found</h3>);
      })
    // setIsSending(false)

    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsSending(false)
    }, 1000);
  }

  const handleChange = (event, nodes) => {

    const arr = nodes;
    const expandingNodes = nodes.filter(x => !expanded.includes(x));
    const secondChar = expandingNodes.length ? expandingNodes[0].charAt(1) : 'z';
    const siblingNodes = arr.filter(x => x.includes(secondChar))

    if (siblingNodes.length > 1 && nodes.indexOf(siblingNodes[1])) {
      nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(siblingNodes[1]), 1)
    }
    let a = nodes.filter(x => siblingNodes.length > 1 && secondChar !== 'a' && !x.includes(secondChar) && x !== expandingNodes[0])
    if (!a.length) {
      a = nodes;
    }
    setExpanded(nodes)

  }

  const applyTitle = (data) => {
    console.log("data", data)
    return (
      // 'testing title'
      <span style={{ color: 'purple' }} >{data.Title}</span>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Filters sendFilterParams={(filterParams) => { sendRequest(filterParams) }}></Filters>
      {
        data && data.length ?
          <div>
            <h3>System Health Report</h3>
            <TreeView
              className={classes.root}
              defaultCollapseIcon={<MinusSquare />}
              defaultExpandIcon={<PlusSquare />}
              defaultEndIcon={<CloseSquare />}
              expanded={expanded}
              onNodeToggle={handleChange}
            >
              {data.map((item, i) => {
                return <StyledTreeItem nodeId={i + "a"} label={item.Title} key={i}>
                  {item && item.ListSecNodes && item.ListSecNodes.length && item.ListSecNodes.map((value, j) => {
                    return (
                      <StyledTreeItem key={j + i} onClick={() => { handleClick(value.Id, 'ListSecNodes') }} nodeId={j + "b"} label={applyTitle(value.Title, value.ForeColor, value.BackColor)}>
                        <div>
                          {
                            !(Array.isArray(value.ListSubNodes) && value.ListSubNodes.length) ? (isSending ? <LinearProgress /> : showTable) :
                              (value && Array.isArray(value.ListSubNodes)) ? value.ListSubNodes.map((nestedItem, k) => {
                                return (
                                  <StyledTreeItem key={i + j + k} onClick={() => { handleClick(nestedItem.SubNodeID, 'ListSubNodes') }} nodeId={k + "c"} label={nestedItem.SubTitle} style={{ backgroundColor: value.BackColor, color: value.ForeColor }}>
                                    <div>
                                      {isSending ? <LinearProgress /> : showTable}
                                    </div>
                                  </StyledTreeItem>
                                )
                              }) : null
                          }
                        </div>
                      </StyledTreeItem>
                    )
                  })}
                </StyledTreeItem>
              })}
            </TreeView>
            {/* {showTable} */}
          </div> : isSending ? <CircularProgress style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '50%' }} /> : null
      }
    </div>

  );
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your full code? Or an online demo?

Comment: Ok, I'll update the full code.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the style of the `TreeItem`'s label using the [`classes`](https://material-ui.com/api/tree-item/#css) property:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  label: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    color: "red"
  }
});

...

<TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
        <TreeItem classes={{ label: classes.label }} nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
        <TreeItem classes={{ label: classes.label }} nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
        <TreeItem
          classes={{ label: classes.label }}
          nodeId="4"
          label="Webstorm"
          icon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        />
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Working example:

[image: Edit Material demo]

You can also use [`withStyles`](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#shorthand) as a shorthand:

```
...

const StyledTreeItem = withStyles({
    label: {
      backgroundColor: "green",
      color: "red"
    },
  })(TreeItem);

  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
        <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
        <StyledTreeItem
          nodeId="4"
          label="Webstorm"
          icon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        />
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
```

Working example:

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Can I apply conditional styling for label? 

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  label: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    color: "red"
  }
});

Comment: Yes, you can pass an object to useStyles: `const classes = useStyles(myObj);` and the makeStyles: `const useStyles = makeStyles({ label: props => ({ backgroundColor: props.bgColor ? props.bgColor : 'green' , color: props.color }) });`. More info [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props)

Comment: Thanks, I'll chek this.